# tsql convert string into date when possible

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I've got a column to import into an `Azure SQL DB` that is supposed to be made of dates only but of course contains errors.

In `TSQL` I would like to do something like: convert to date if it's possible otherwise null.

Does anyone know a statement to test the convertibility of a string into a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`TRY_PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx):

> **Returns the result of an expression, translated to the requested data type, or null if the cast fails.** Use `TRY_PARSE` only for converting from string to date/time and number types.

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('20129901' AS DATE)
-- NULL
```

Additionaly you could add culture:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('10/25/2015' AS DATE USING 'en-US')
```

---

And importing:

```
INSERT INTO target_table(date_column, ...)
SELECT TRY_PARSE(date_string_column AS DATE) ...
FROM source_table
...
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

use TryCast or Isdate

```
select 
try_Cast('test' as date)
select try_Cast('4' as  date) 

select case when ISDATE('test')=1 then cast('test' as date) else null end
```

TryCast will fail if the expression is not in expected format ..ie.,if the explicit conversion of expression is not permitted

```
select 
try_cast( 4 as xml)
select try_Cast(4 as date)
```

Comment: This is even better Thank you